# C# - How do I pass the elements in my array to the properties in the class

Tags: c#

I am creating a program that will calculate tne room size based off the values sent to the length, width and height properties. I have stored the values in the array named roomArray which stores the length, width and height for 4 room sizes. I need to send those values to the properties in the room class as it can then return the room size and gallons of paint needed to paint the room. The elements in the array are stored in the order of length, width & height. I am stuck as I do not know how to send the elements from the array. The goal is to pass all the measurements to the 4 rooms in the array and the output will show the total room area and the gallons of paint needed to paint each room. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Array;

namespace PaintingRoomDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Room aRoom = new Room();
            int[,] roomArray = { {12, 10, 9},
                                 {11, 8, 12 },
                                 {10, 10, 8 },
                                 {15, 12, 10} };

            Write("The room area is: {0} gallons of paint needed is {1}",
                aRoom.WallArea, aRoom.GallonsOfPaint);
            ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class Room
    {
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int WallArea
        {
            get { return CalcWallArea(); }
        }
        public int GallonsOfPaint
        {
            get { return CalcAmountOfPaint(); }
        }
        private int CalcWallArea()
        {
            // I am assuming this calculation is correct for your needs.
            return (Length + Width + Length + Width) * Height;
        }
        private int CalcAmountOfPaint()
        {
            var area = WallArea;
            if (area <= 350)
                return 1;

            int x = 0;
            while (area > 0)
            {
                x++;
                area -= 350;
            }
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, your `CalcAmountOfPaint` method can be simplified to: `return (int)Math.Ceiling(WallArea / 350.0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to have a Room constructor with Length,Width,Height and\or even better if you have initialized them as:

```
List<Room> rooms = List<Room> {
                      new Room {Length=12, Width=10, Height= 9},
                      new Room {Length=11, Width= 8, Height=12},
                      new Room {Length=10, Width=10, Height= 8},
                      new Room {Length=15, Width=12, Height=10},
                   };
```

With the way you are doing, you can do:

```
void Main()
{
    int[,] roomArray = { {12, 10, 9},
                         {11, 8, 12 },
                         {10, 10, 8 },
                         {15, 12, 10} };
    List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();

    for (int row = 0; row < roomArray.GetLength(0); row++) {
       rooms.Add(new Room{ 
             Length = roomArray[row, 0], 
             Width  = roomArray[row, 1],
             Height = roomArray[row, 2]
        });
    }       
    foreach(var aRoom in rooms)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Room LxWxH is: {0},{1},{2}", aRoom.Length, aRoom.Width, aRoom.Height);
      Console.WriteLine("The room area is: {0} gallons of paint needed is {1}",
         aRoom.WallArea, aRoom.GallonsOfPaint);
    }
    ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: you are awesome sir and that worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can just convert your array to a `List<Room>` using a for loop:

```
List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
for (int i = 0; i < roomArray.Length / 3; i++)
    rooms.add(new Room {
                          Width = roomArray[i, 0],
                          Height = roomArray[i, 1],
                          Length = roomArray[i, 2] 
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create an array of rooms instead? Like this.

```
Room[] rooms = new Room[4] {
   new Room(1, 5, 9),
   new Room(12, 35, 9),
   new Room(18, 25, 9),
   new Room(1, 5, 19)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in contructor of room:

```
private int[,] details;   

    public Room(int[,] Details)
    {
    details = Details;
    }
```

Now you can use it in your calculations

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
int[][] roomArray = 
{
    new [] {12, 10, 9},
    new [] {11, 8, 12},
    new [] {10, 10, 8},
    new [] {15, 12, 10}
};
roomArray.Select(x => new Room
    {
        Length = x[0],
        Width = x[1],
        Height = x[2],
    })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x =>
    {
        Write($"The room area is: {x.WallArea} gallons of paint needed is {x.GallonsOfPaint}");
    });
```

Comment: you are awesome sir and that worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: you guys are awesome. I will try your approach also. Thank you so much.